# Finding a formula to generate an arbitrary sequence using binomial coefficients, why does this work?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across this method to find a formula for an arbitrary sequence, and I'm stumped trying to understand **why** it works.

Consider the sequence $1, 9, 10, 12, 15$

The first step is to find the difference between consecutive terms, until:

- we get equal difference between all terms, *or*
- we get only a single term.

So,

$$1, 9, 10, 12, 15$$

becomes

$$8, 1, 2, 3$$

$$-7, 1, 1$$

$$8, 0$$

$$8$$

We got to a single term so we can stop.

Now all we need to do is to construct the formula using the first term of every sequence. Each sequence's first term is the coefficient and the $k$ value of the binomial coefficient is the "sequence's index" (or row index) starting with $0$.

So in this case we end up with

$$1\binom{n}{0}+8\binom{n}{1}-7\binom{n}{2}+8\binom{n}{3}+8\binom{n}{4}$$

$$...$$

$$ f(n) = \frac{(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n}{3} + \frac{4(n-2)(n-1)n}{3} - \frac{7(n-1)n}{2}+8n+1$$

And indeed we can verify that this formula generates our sequence:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{f(n)} \\
\hline
0 & 1  \\
1 & 9  \\
2 & 10 \\
3 & 12 \\
4 & 15 \\
.. & .. 
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we can always construct a polynomial through an arbitrary amount of points we can conclude that $f(x)$ exists and is a polynomial.

[Newton's forward difference formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsForwardDifferenceFormula.html) then tells us that

$$f(x + a) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{a}{k} \Delta^k f(x)$$

where $\Delta^k f$ is the function resulting from  $k$ applications of the forward difference operator $\Delta$ to $f$.

Your formula is a direct result from setting $a = n$ and $x = 0$.